# Paging combo box in extjs 3

Tags: java, extjs

I am trying to implement paging in combo box. Paging tool bar will appear on the combo box  if we specify pageSize. But how the call will raised while clicking on next page symbol.
Data is taken from postgre db . Server side code contains Guice & Java application.

Thanks
Syam

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Paging Toolbar extension? It keeps track of next/previous everything - you just need to add the store in config and maintain data limit from backend.

Check the combobox with pagingbar from this [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/forum-search.html).